# Why is this Javascript code returning undefined

Tags: javascript

This is an IIFE function provided with a string. The inner function is not taking the string parameter because it is printing `undefined` in console

```js
//jshint esnext: true
    
(function(string) {
  var s = setTimeout((string) => {
    console.log(string);
  }, 1000);
})("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Some people might have just called it a trivial misuse of API, or just having poor quality in general. Regardless, multiple downvotes invite you to improve your question with further research and a better description of what is troubling you. In this case, did you try some debugging before asking? It also looks like you're using jshint. Did you include linting rules for detecting variable name collisions or incorrect function parameter list declarations?

Comment: By being more pragmatic and focusing on the question rather than expressing out hatred for downvoters, you will be able to provide better contributions to the site in the future.

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, but I suppose StackOverflow is there for asking doubts rather than seeking contributions from newbies. I did try - same code on JSBin and Codepen. It was nowhere in my mind the fact that setTimeout doesn't take arguments.

Comment: @E_net4 What I am saying is yes this was silly, but nobody has to show it this way to bring down the morale of a guy who is trying hands on a tricky language like Javascript.

Comment: Again, that does not invalidate the poor quality of the question. I did nothing more than explain that to you in words. Your statement of Stack Overflow not seeking contributions from newbies is also misguided: We accept questions from _anyone_, just as long as those questions are good enough.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) doesn't invoke its callback function with any arguments:

```js
(function(string) {
  var s = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(string);
  }, 1000);
})("Hello World!");
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly pass the parameter to the callback function, but this is not necessary:

```js
(function(string) {
  var s = setTimeout((param) => {
    console.log(param);
  }, 1000, string);
})("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `string` inside the `setTimeout` is shadowed by the `setTimeout` callback parameter. This might make it more clear what your code is currently doing:

```
(function(a) {
  var s = setTimeout((b) => {
    console.log(b);
  }, 1000);
})("Hello World!");
```

If you want to close over the `a` parameter, then just don't use a param for the `setTimeout` callback:

```
(function(a) {
  var s = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(a);
  }, 1000);
})("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a function to `setTimeout` that takes a parameter named `string`.

`setTimeout` doesn't pass any parameters when it calls your callback, so it gets `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

As per official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to pass any parameter to the inner function, you need to specify it after `delay` value:

> setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...])

```js
(function(s) {
  var id = setTimeout(function(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }, 1000, s);
})("Hello World!");
```

It is advised to always define passed parameter, as the outer scope variable value may change later on in the code:

```js
(function(s) {
  var id = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(s);
  }, 1000);
  s = "Bye Bye";
})("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Sure it does mate. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if applicable.